# How do I add values to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, datasource, datagridviewcombobox

I have an issue wherein I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in a `DataGridView` and I want to add an item to the `DataSource`.

I've initially set the DataSource property to a `List<string>` which works fine. Later I'll add an item to this list, which works fine. But when I try to choose this item in a combobox, I get a data validation error,

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Further, I can't actually set the combobox to the newly added value.

Here is a fully working example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> Data { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Populate our data source
        this.Data = new List<string> { "Thing1", "Thing2" };

        // Set up controls
        var gvData = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        var col1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        var button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

        gvData.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { col1 });

        // Set the column's DataSource
        col1.DataSource = this.Data;
        col1.HeaderText = "Test";
        col1.Name = "col1";

        // Set up a button which adds something to the source
        button.Text = "Add";
        button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 200);
        button.Click += (e, s) => this.Data.Add("Thing3");

        this.Controls.Add(gvData);
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

How can I add items to the `DataSource` for my `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`?

Comment: Where are you doing / calling DataBind() Method..? I believe also that you need to assign the Combobox's `ValueMember and DisplayMember` just quickly taking a glance

Comment: @DJKRAZE I hadn't set them because I read that for `string` values it shouldn't matter. I will try now. I don't know about `DataBind`. I have never used that method when setting a data source in WinForms.

Comment: DataBind() normally used in DataGridview but I was just noticing some other things in regards to the actual combobox that's why I mentioned it

Comment: The DataGridView doesn't seem to have a `DataBind` method. I looked into `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`, but I don't know how to set them. They are supposed to be properties of my objects, but my objects are just strings.

Comment: @DJKRAZE [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databind.aspx) is for ASP.Net

Comment: @KrisHarper Your code works fine on my machine. What is not working?

Comment: `Jacob` that's correct I just realized he's doing winforms sorry

Comment: @JacobSeleznev [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/RwsSo9Q.png) of the error that pops up. The exact steps to reproduce are 1. Set a value in the first row of the grid. Make sure you are no longer in edit mode. 2. Click the button to add a value. 3. Attempt to change the value previously set. I immediately get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

`button.Click += (e, s) => this.Data.Add("Thing3");`

to

```
           button.Click += (e, s) =>
           {
                col1.DataSource = null;
                this.Data.Add("Thing3");
                col1.DataSource = Data;
           };
```

has worked for me.

Comment: While this gets rid of the message, it has a number of other side effects. Most importantly, setting the `DataSource` to `null` clears the values of every row currently in the grid. Secondly, the add button now adds a second column with heading "Length." Thirdly, the grid now appears to be buggy. Choosing "Thing3" more than once results in an NRE.

Comment: You are setting DataSource of **col1**, right? It shouldn't affect every datagrid's row.

Comment: Kris, i did not experience any of the side-effects you mentioned. I just took your test code from the question body, and replaced the Click handler as Jacob suggested... And it worked an intended, no lost values, no second column, and no NREs...